# Create trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a trigger in Mysql.
Before Insert and before Update , to only insert the values if the ID is present in another table.

Here is my trigger (before insert) which does not work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 
    `before_insert_id`
BEFORE INSERT ON
    `table2`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
        IF NEW.id = 
            ( SELECT id
              FROM table2
              WHERE NEW.id not in (select id from table1)
            )
        THEN 
            SET msg = 'id not in table1';
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002' SET message_text = msg ;
        END IF ;
    END ;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also should we insert values in table2 inside after if statement passes?or is it just for checking only?

Comment: //to only insert the values if the ID is present in another table.//   you mention you want to insert if ID is present in another table.. but  using  NOT IN

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS (select * from table1 where id = new.id)  then
set msg = 'id not in table1'
signal...
end if;

If it exists then data gets inserted automatically.

Comment: This suggestion works

Comment: Mark it as solution.. for others to benefit from it.

Comment: Not sure how to mark the comment as a solution.If you can write it in the answer.I will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF NOT EXISTS (select * from table1 where id = new.id) then set msg = 'id not in table1' signal... end if; If it exists then data gets inserted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> ... only insert the values if the ID is present in another table.

This sound like you just need a foreign key constraint, not a trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table1(id);
```

That will throw an error if you try to insert a row with an `id` that is *not* present in table1.

No trigger required.

Comment: The values in the "id" column are not unique.For each id, there are multiple rows.I tried it now but not working.

Comment: InnoDB doesn't require the referenced column to be unique, but it must be the first column in some index. This is a little bit different from the traditional type of foreign key, but it might be useful in your case.